# HDD not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I have a 1TB internal hard drive, i made a 140 gb partition to install Ubuntu alongside windows,my windows is installed on an 256gb ssd which is visible in - files, but my other 860gb partition of hdd is not visible there

[Image of This Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPWTf.png)

I installed gparted and it recognises my other hdd partition...heres a screenshot

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hHgh.png)

In front of the 791 gb partition, it shows LDM data partition and i am not sure what that means, so I just needed help cause i will definately run out of space...just how do i access the other partition on ubuntu

Comment: Windows partitions are generally NTFS formatted, so you'll need to have the proper package installed ahead of time: `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. So long as the Windows partitions are not encrypted, you may be able to mount them afterwards.